# Using regular expressions to check for a minimum number of characters?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I have the following code to validate usernames for an application:

```
Regex usernameRegex = new Regex("[A-Za-z0-9_]");
if (usernameRegex.IsMatch(MyTextBox.Text)) {
    // Create account, etc.
}
```

How would I modify my regular expression to check if the username has a certain number of characters?

Comment: [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) was found quite quickly be searching for .NET Regular Expressions.

Comment: I think what he's asking is how to match a minimum number of _characters_, not a minimum number.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression validates only all text which contains any combination of  `A to Z`, `a to z` and number `0 to 9`. You can define the length of the string using the regex:

```
Regex reg= new Regex(@"^[A-Z]{3,}[a-z]{2,}\d*$")
```

`{3,}` and `{2,}` mean here that the string must have at least 3 capital characters, at least 2 small characters, and any amount of digit characters.

For example : 
Valid : AAAbb, AAAbb2, AAAAAAbbbbb, AAAAAbbbbbb4343434

Invalid: AAb, Abb, AbAbabA, 1AAAbb,

Comment: i know, i was asking how to set the minimum number of characters

Answer (score 0):

To set a minimum (or maximum) range in a regular expression you can use the `{from,to}` syntax.

The following will only match a string with a minimum of 5 alpha numeric and underscore characters:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_]{5,}
```

And the following will match a minimum of 5 and maximum of 10:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_]{5,10}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[A-Za-z0-9_]
```

`[] "brackets":` are a group of characters you want to match.

`A-Z:` means it will match any alphabet capitalized within this range A-Z.

`a-z:` means it will match any small alphabet within this range a-z.

`0-9:` means it will match any digit in this range 0-9.

`_:` means it will match the "_" character.

now this regex will usually match the following: any character from a to z (small, capital), any number (from 0-9) and the underscore "_".

i.e. "a.,.B.,10.._" this will match "a, B, 10, _". but of course you need to add the singleline regex option.